# Is $\pi_m(M) = 0$ if $\pi_m(M-X) = 0$ for a low-dimensional subset $X$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, manifolds

I am doing a problem where I am stuck at this point.

> Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold of dimension $n$ and let $X$ be any subset of $M$. Assume that there is a positive integer $m$ such that $n>2m, ~\dim X < n-m$ and $\pi_m(M-X)=0$. Then is it true that $\pi_m(M)=0$?

Here $\dim X$ is the [topological dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) of the space $X$. If $X$ is a submanifold, then this result is true ([I asked the same question on math stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668204/is-pi-mm-0?noredirect=1#comment9865506_4668204)). I want if it is true for a general (closed) subset $X$.

Any hint/reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Let $f:S_m\to M$ be a continuous map of the sphere. Your condition on dimensions implies that $f$ can be perturbed a little so that the image does not hit $X$. Since this perturbed $f$ is homotopic to a point in $M\backslash X$, $f$ is homotopic to a point in $M$.

Comment: Smooth out with the Whitney's smoothing and then apply Sard's theorem.

Comment: I assume that when you say you want a general closed subset to have dimension less than $n-m$, that you mean $X$ is covered by a countable union of submanifolds of dimension $n-m-1$, so you can apply Sard.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, I do not know if you can perturb $f$ as explained. If $X$ is a submanifold, then we can (by using the transversality argument).  Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @BenMcKay Yes you are right about the dimension less than $n-m$, but how are you applying Sard's to conclude this?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad: sorry, I meant to write that you use Whitney's smoothing results to homotope your map $S^n\to M$ to a smooth map, and then Thom transversality to smoothly homotope to a map which doesn't strike $X$.